# Chrome and rgb colors

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've just faced a strange thing... HTML code like a

```
<font ... color=rgb(0,85,0)>Hello World</font>
```

in FF and IE it is green but in Google Chrome the color is something like brown :S

So my question is how to set a proper rgb color format for google chrome?

Comment: When I use the font tag it is brown, but green in the span. Maybe you should avoid deprecated tags... either way it doesn't make sense. http://jsfiddle.net/MvnJE/

Comment: By the way, can I congratulate you on finding a difference between Safari and Chrome. (Latest versions, under Windows) Normally, they act like the identical twins they are, but Safari goes green here, while Chrome chooses brown.

Comment: By the way, in font tags color like rgb(0,0,0) chrome shows as red :S

Comment: Yes, and purple if you use rgb(0,0,0,b). It's trying to interpret as a hex color, ignoring the rb and using the rest as hex digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<font color=rgb(0,85,0)>` is not valid HTML.

Aside from the fact that you should put quotes around the attribute value and that `font` is deprecated, `font` is guaranteed to work only with color names and 6-digit hex values. See the [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-color).

If you need other ways of specifying your color, use a style.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this in your HTML:

```
<div id="helloDiv">Hello World</div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#helloDiv { color: rgb(0, 85, 0); }
```

It appears to render the same color in Chrome as FF and IE.